# What is this black nut/gasket on my main water line?

Tags: water

On the main water line to my house, there is a black gasket that seems to be leaking.  What is that black nut on top?  Have you seen this kind of thing before? I want to know if I can just tighten it with a wrench or if I need to turn of water line and replace it.

[image: leaking rubber gasket]

Comment: Do you have an irrigation system? From what I can see that's part of a backflow preventer.   Also if you have winter where you are, water pipes not drained for winter would need to be buried below the frostline, which these clearly are not.

Comment: @Tyson yes, that pipe is right next to the irrigation system, so maybe I'm wrong and this isn't an incoming pipe.

Comment: It's appears from the pic it's a test port on the irrigation systems backflow preventer.  Since you didn't know what the part is, I'm guessing you have a company or person that maintains the system for you, call them.

Comment: @tyson thanks! you helped me realize the problem.  It's a test cock on a backflow preventer and there is an easy way to turn it off.

Answer (score 3):

The picture turns out to be a picture of a test cock on a backflow preventer.  The black plug is just cosmetic.  One the side there is a way to use a flathead screwdriver and [turn off the test cock](http://www.cityraininc.com/closing-test-cocks-on-the-double-check/) (in my case, it had been slightly open).

Comment: Man, this site is good!

Comment: Black plug is likely more than cosmetic, it would be a cap to stop any dirt and debris getting in.